# How to hide NGINX name in an installed instance

Tags: nginx

I have a website works with nginx. I want to hide the nginx name in http headers, is there any way to hide nginx name without uninstalling and reinstalling ??

Comment: put `server_tokens off;` inside nginx.conf

Comment: this just hides nginx version, not it's name.

Answer (score 1):

> easy to delete follow this process

## install

```
yum install nginx-module-headers-more;

vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

## add_php version_server_nginx hide narayan

load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;

server_tokens off;

fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;

more_clear_headers Server;

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it or disable using below

**Change It**

```
server_tokens "off";
more_set_headers "Server: Your_New_Server_Name";
```

or

**Delete it**

```
server_tokens "off";
more_clear_headers   "Server";
```

> PS: Above requires the module https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/headers_more/

On the commercial version you can just do

```
server_tokens "";
```

And this will disable the server tokens

Comment: the "more_set_headers" isn't installed.

Comment: which OS are you on?

Comment: I use debian 8.

Comment: run `apt-get install nginx-extras` and see if you get the module

Comment: This does not remove the nginx branding from redirects and error pages. `curl http(s)://(www.)yournewnginxwebsite.com/a/redirected/link`